# Uncalled header issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a word-press theme and whenever I add the code below to, it adds 20px space at the top of the website, offsetting the background. I've adjusted the CSS but it reflect any changes. Any idea what the problem could be.

```
<?php wp_head();?>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have accidentally put a character out of place? I fought a similar issue because I put a double >> and I couldn't see the extra character but it pushed the website down a bit since it was above my header. It would be easiest to answer if we could see the page.

Comment: That's a huge line pf codes bro. If becomes okay whenever I take it off.

Comment: wp_head() resides inside head tag right before closing head tag and it has nothing to do with inside body with such a thing you've mentioned here.

Comment: Krembo it's arount 20px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that I"m logged in as an admin and the admin bar way supposed to be covering that space but apparently, it wasn't showing. I did find out because  it only happens when I'm logged in,in the same browser.

Comment: It's OK when I'm logged out or when tested on another browser. If you're witnessing the same problem rest your work on another browser or log-gout before you test your work.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're missing the   call at the bottom?